# Having parametrized class in swagger annotations

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, spring-rest

From my spring rest service, I am returning response as -

```
return new ResponseEntity<ExampleOutputData>(exampleService.exampleServiceCall(inputData), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

And I am mentioning response in annotaion as -

```
 @ApiResponses(value = { 
            @ApiResponse(code = 202, message = "Success", response = ResponseEntity.class)})
```

And I am getting yaml doc response as -

```
  responses:
    202:
      description: "Success"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ResponseEntity"
```

My question is how do I mention ExampleOutputData in the response as actually my response is `ResponseEntity<ExampleOutputData>`

Or is it not required and the current implementation and swagger definition is perfect?

Comment: Are you using http://Springfox.io? If you don't need to add any special annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have ExampleOutputData in the response you should simply change `ResponseEntity.class` to `ExampleOutputData.class`:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 202, message = "Success", response = ExampleOutputData.class)})
```

See documentation [here](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiResponse.html).